# Laravel raw sql query returns empty array result

Tags: mysql, laravel, query-builder

I have this raw query where in it works in mysql but not in laravel 5.7

```
$lat = '25.2645684753';
$long = '55.3381347656';
```

the `$lat` and `$long` is a request input btw.

```
$distance = DB::table('company')
            ->select(DB::raw('ROUND(111.045* haversine(latitude,longitude,'.$lat.', '.$long.'),2) AS distance_in_km'))
            ->orderBy('distance_in_km', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```

the result shows **empty []**

I checked the query using ->tosql() and run it in the mysql without any errors and with a result.

```
SELECT ROUND(111.045* haversine(latitude,longitude,25.2645684753, 55.3381347656),2) AS distance_in_km FROM `company` ORDER BY `distance_in_km` ASC
```

Comment: Is laravel definitely accessing the same instance of MySQL? Perhaps the haversine() function is missing?

Comment: not sure why haversine function in the database is not working in the laravel. its already in the mysql database.  I used laravel scope instead. Thanks for the reply. @Strawberry